# Reference user control command from main application WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, livecharts

I am using this code example from live charts

https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes%20II

It's in my application and working however I want to be able to access the "ReadCommand" from outside the user control, implement my own buttons and later send over the values I am reading from the serial port. How can i access the user control from my main application?

I have tried this after looking on various other posts but am struggling to get my head around this.

```
 <Button x:Name="btn_StartTest"  Command="{Binding ReadCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:GraphData}}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="START" Grid.Column="18" Grid.Row="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="5,0" Click="btn_StartTest_Click"/>
```

Comment: Where is btn_StartTest located in the visual tree and where is the UC located? A RelativeSource binding will only work if the UC is a visual parent of the Button.

Comment: @mm8 I have never looked at the visual tree (looking up how to now!) But i would assume it's not a visual parent

Comment: Apparently not since the binding doesn't work.

Comment: @mm8 In that case how would i go about binding?

Comment: You need to make sure that the Button inherits the same DataContext as the UserControl.

Comment: @mm8 Im assuming this has  something to do with it    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:GraphData></local:GraphData>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

This is on my graph control xaml

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 I avoided posted the whole code as it is exactly the same as the example in the link I have simply added a button to the page where the user control has been added